# Pinch to lock iPhone

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I've been having issues with my iPhone 5's lock button recently, I'm having to press it more forcefully to get it to work. Then I saw [this video](http://youtu.be/R3C6OW8eMGk) and got to a part where the person does a pinch gesture to lock his phone.

Is this a feature to iPhone 5S only or can this be unlocked through some set up in accessibility?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he's using a custom gesture on a jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Ah alright, I just noticed the jailbroken app store in the bottom corner. Thanks

Comment: if you are adventurous you might be able to get your button working again with a bit of wd40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom gesture set up on the jailbroken iPhone. Pinch to lock is not a feature available in Accessibility or any other method on a non-jailbroken phone.

The gesture can be set up using a tweak such as [Activator](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/libactivator/). Go to Settings → Activator → On Lock Screen → Icon Pinch → Lock Device to set it up.